# i need help installing zoom on my system

Tags: zoom-meeting

SOLVED thank you!

I have an Intel core I5 2300 system and i cant install zoom meeting. i need hwlp as this is important to me. my system is to old to run win10 successfully. ubuntu studio 21.10 runs smoothly and then some.

Comment: Please edit the question and tells which part of the instructions https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux you don't understand.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1369908/edit) and add more information. What errors you get when you try to install zoom?

Comment: It would be helpful if you a) tell exactly what do you do; b) what happens when you do this.  That said, I run zoom on i3-2310M (10 years old laptop) under ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 2):

This can be installed [via the Software Center](https://snapcraft.io/install/zoom-client/ubuntu). You can also do it via the command line:

```
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

If you would rather install Zoom with a Debian package, the steps and list of dependencies are listed [on Zoom's support page](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux#h_89c268b4-2a68-4e4c-882f-441e374b87cb).

Comment: i found it!!! it was burried down some. youd think it would come on top as it starts with the letter z and had the word zoom in it, but its zoom-client. i am super thankful. thnak you.